# Meaning of the frequencies vector using fft

Tags: fft, frequency-domain, time-domain

I'm so confused, and it would be nice if someone could clear my head, or at least direct me to suitable references.

Assume that I have two gaussian pulses with the same bandwidth in time, but for 2 different wavelengths. I'm going to handle them separatly- 2 separate graphs of one gaussian in time.

Both graphs are the same because they have the same bandwidth.
Then, I use fft on each graph.
Of course I'm going to have the same graphs after the fft- because I had the same graphs before.

Now, I want to creat the frequencies axis for each signal. In order to do that, I use the exact direction from matlab. df=1/T,  T=N·dt.
So the frequencies axis are also the same!

But how can it be if f=c/lambda?  I'm talking about two different wave length, how is it possible that the both have the same spectrum of frequencies?

Further more, I don't understand what is the different between F and df and why is F=N·df. I do understand that T is the time in which I sample, dt=T/N. but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You forget that what you did was describing the passband signals (i.e. some waveform on a carrier frequency == on a wavelength) in baseband.

So, of course, after calculating the baseband spectrum, you need to shift it back where it came from - to the carrier frequency. It's as easy as that.

If this isn't clear to you, you might want to revisit what (complex equivalent) *baseband* and *passband* are.

Comment: But why did I describe my passband in baseband? where in the process? 
Thank you.

Comment: in the end of your question you're trying to consider the spectrum of the signal *on* the carriers. That's passband. Really, read up on baseband and passband signals – this doesn't seem to be clear to you, and it's literally in every textbook on communications engineering, in many on signals and systems, …

Comment: thank you so much for your help!